# plots to show whether the observed data is contained within a distribution

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, simulation, ggplot2

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(year = 1980:2014, y = rnorm(35))
```

For each year, I have a model that predicts ~5000 values of `y` and I am interested in examining whether the `y` in each year is contained within the predicted 5000 values. I am looking for some ideas on the type of plots to show such results. Suppose `df1` is the data frame that holds the 5000 predicted y values for each year.

```
df1 <- data.frame(year = rep(1980:2014, each = 5000), y.pred = rnorm(5000 * 35))
```

I have two types of plots in mind:

## Plot 1: boxplot of 5000 predicted values

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = y.pred)) + geom_boxplot() +
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = y), colour = "red", shape = 19, size = 2)
```

[image]

## Plot 2: calculate mean, 95% CI for each year

```
  df1.summary <- df1 %>% dplyr::group_by(year) %>% dplyr::summarise(mean.y = mean(y.pred), upCI.y = quantile(y.pred, probs = 0.975),lwCI.y = quantile(y.pred, probs = 0.025))

  ggplot(df1.summary, aes(x = year, y = mean.y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lwCI.y, ymax = upCI.y), width = .2) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = year, y = y), colour = "red", shape = 19, size = 2)
```

[image]

Does anyone have any more ideas on how to present such results graphically?

Thank you